# unhashable type: 'dict' error when checking if key exists

Tags: python-3.x

I want to check if a key exists within a json response but im current getting the error shown in the title;

Here is my code;

```
for i in range(len(MoviesLoadedData)):
     URL_1080p = ""
     if MoviesLoadedData[i]['torrents']['en']['1080p'] in MoviesLoadedData[i]['torrents']['en']:
        URL_1080p = MoviesLoadedData[i]['torrents']['en']['1080p']['url']
     else:
         pass
```

Heres the json response;

```
{
    "_id": "tt1408101",
    "imdb_id": "tt1408101",
    "title": "Star Trek Into Darkness",
    "torrents": {
        "en": {
            "1080p": {
                "url": "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:BF5529C12559DB47FEA3E57BC7ECE827D188589B&tr=udp://glotorrents.pw:6969/announce&tr=udp://tracker.opentrackr.org:1337/announce&tr=udp://torrent.gresille.org:80/announce&tr=udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80&tr=udp://tracker.coppersurfer.tk:6969&tr=udp://tracker.leechers-paradise.org:6969&tr=udp://p4p.arenabg.ch:1337&tr=udp://tracker.internetwarriors.net:1337",
                "seed": 803,
                "peer": 169,
                "size": 2093796557,
                "filesize": "1.95 GB",
                "provider": "YTS"
            },
            "720p": {
                "url": "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:A73CEF306766938EA033DD373FD30337696A8E39&tr=udp://glotorrents.pw:6969/announce&tr=udp://tracker.opentrackr.org:1337/announce&tr=udp://torrent.gresille.org:80/announce&tr=udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80&tr=udp://tracker.coppersurfer.tk:6969&tr=udp://tracker.leechers-paradise.org:6969&tr=udp://p4p.arenabg.ch:1337&tr=udp://tracker.internetwarriors.net:1337",
                "seed": 428,
                "peer": 90,
                "size": 967615447,
                "filesize": "922.79 MB",
                "provider": "YTS"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: That's not valid Python code, identifiers can't start with digits. Please give a [mcve].

Comment: @jonrsharpe sure, i'll change it.

Comment: `else: pass` serves no purpose.

Comment: @khelwood u right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if `'1080p'` is a key in the dict
`MoviesLoadedData[i]['torrents']['en']`, 
then you want:

```
if '1080p' in MoviesLoadedData[i]['torrents']['en']:
```

What you were checking is if the dict
`MoviesLoadedData[i]['torrents']['en']['1080p']` is a key, which is impossible, since a dict cannot be a hash key.

Answer (score 0):

This should make it:

```
if MoviesLoadedData[i]['torrents']['en']['1080p']:
    url_1080p = MoviesLoadedData[i]['torrents']['en']['1080p']['url']
    print(url_1080p)
```